# Disabling New Folder Button in File chooser not working properly

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I disable the new Folder button using the following code:

```
 public void disableNewFolderButton( Container c ) {

     System.out.print("in disable fn");
int len = c.getComponentCount();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  Component comp = c.getComponent(i);
  if (comp instanceof JButton) {
    JButton b = (JButton)comp;
    Icon icon = b.getIcon();
    if (icon != null
         && icon == UIManager.getIcon("FileChooser.newFolderIcon"))
    {
        System.out.print("in disable fn");
       b.setEnabled(false);
    }
    }
  else if (comp instanceof Container) {
    disableNewFolderButton((Container)comp);
  }
}
 }
```

The code is called in the following lines:

```
   JFileChooser of=new JFileChooser();
    of.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    of.addChoosableFileFilter(new MyFilter());
    disableNewFolderButton(of);
```

But the new folder button is disabled only when the file chooser is first displayed. Suppose i go to some drive , say g: , then the button is enabled again. How to set this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is working for me...

```
    //Create a file chooser
UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", Boolean.TRUE); 
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
```

Comment: +1 This one works great for me. Though I would prefer on not involving UIManager. Yet I couldn't find a better one. Plus this solution also hides the 'New folder' in the popup menu. Thanks. I wonder here how to use this solution for just one file chooser?

Comment: For only one FileChooser, call `UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", Boolean.TRUE);` before making and showing the file chooser and `UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", Boolean.FALSE);` afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

Disable the "new folder" Action (which in turn will disable the button):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class FileChooserAction
{
    public static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

        BasicFileChooserUI ui = (BasicFileChooserUI)chooser.getUI();
        Action folder = ui.getNewFolderAction();
        folder.setEnabled(false);

        chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: weird but this example doesn't work for me and 'logically' it should. Do you have any suggestions as to reasons why is it this way?

Comment: @Boro, I use JDK6_07 on XP. The posted code work for me with the Metal and Windows LAF's. I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you, it must be a platform/LAF issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are completely right, it is dependent, in this case JDK dependent. It is all fine when I run 6.0_11 but not when 6.0_25 (my current JDK).

Comment: appreciated your input and solution +1. I wonder if they will sort out this issue in newer JDK.

Answer (score 0):

1) It is a bit stupid, but you can keep disabling it in an another Thread. Until the file chooser got invisible.
2) Does hiding the button work? `b.setVisible(false);`

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but works fine. Thanks Martjin